# Angular template not available after installing Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*

Tags: .net, angular

I'm trying to get stated with .Net today and have installed the SDK. I've read that I need to install the SPA template using the CLI command:

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

This command executed but I do not have any of the frameworks available. Though according to tutorials on the web I should see MVC templates [LIKE THIS ONE](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2017/02/14/building-single-page-applications-on-asp-net-core-with-javascriptservices/)

[image]

What might be the reason that I cannot see Angular, Knockout, React, etc.? How can I get the template?

I'm using a mac and installed the sdk via https://www.microsoft.com/net/download/core.

Answer (score 2):

please upgrade your sdk from 1 to 2 because only 2 support angular

Answer (score 0):

I was running into the same issue when I had .Net Core 1.1.0 SDK. I was able to fix the issue by upgrading to .Net Core 2.0.0 and running

```
dotnet new --install Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaTemplates::*
```

After this, the angular template (and others) were available.